# Cannot align text field inside a stack pane

Tags: java, javafx, alignment

[image]

I have a `StackPane` where I need to add four text fields and a chart. These text fields will be used to set the range of the chart axes. I chose `StackPane` because it rescales nicely (together with the chart) in the dock pane in which it is later included. I didn't embed the text fields in a `VBox` or `HBox` because they gave me troubles with a zooming rectangle (scalable) added later to the pane.

Everything works apart from the fact that I am not able to set the distance between the `TextField`s and `StackPane` near borders. All I could control is the general positioning like `pane.setAlignment(upperY, Pos.TOP_LEFT)`. But this means that two of my `TextField`s overlap in the bottom-left corner. Anyone knows how to fix this, either through CSS or directly in the Java code?

I tried setting `-fx-alignment` in the CSS. I tried changing the type of pane. I tried setting border insets in the CSS etc.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    static LineChart<Number, Number> chart; 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
        {

            TextField upperY = new TextField("upperY");  upperY.getStylesheets().add("css/chart.css"); 
            TextField lowerY = new TextField("lowerY");  lowerY.getStylesheets().add("css/chart.css"); 
            TextField rightX = new TextField("rightX");  rightX.getStylesheets().add("css/chart.css"); 
            TextField leftX = new TextField("leftX");  leftX.getStylesheets().add("css/chart.css"); 


            StackPane pane = new StackPane();
            HBox.setHgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);
            VBox.setVgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);

            pane.setAlignment(upperY, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
            pane.setAlignment(lowerY, Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
            pane.setAlignment(rightX, Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            pane.setAlignment(leftX, Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

            chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());

            pane.getChildren().addAll(chart, upperY, lowerY, leftX, rightX);

            Pane root = new Pane();
            root.getChildren().add(pane);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } // end start

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```css
.text-field{
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
    -fx-min-width: 35;
    -fx-pref-width: 35;
    -fx-max-width: 35;    
    -fx-min-height: 18;
    -fx-pref-height: 18; 
    -fx-max-height: 18;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Narrow";
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-alignment: BASELINE_CENTER;
    -fx-padding: -2 2 0 2;  /*   // T R B L*/  
    -fx-background-color: white; 
    -fx-control-inner-background: white;
    -fx-border-color: lightgray;
    -fx-border-insets: 0 0 0 0; 
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

I need to push the `leftX` text field to the right and the `lowerY` text field upwards a little bit.

Comment: If you do know the size of the nodes, you could use [the `margin` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#setMargin(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.geometry.Insets)) or use a `AnchorPane`. I cannot think of a reason why this would be preferable to wrapping multiple nodes in a `HBox`/`VBox` though. Not sure what your issue with those is...

Comment: Thanks fabian. I attached a picture now. The problem with imposing insets/margin on the StackPane is that it reduces the space available to the chart. And this won't prevent my two text fields overlapping at the bottom-left corner. I need something to independently displace each text field

Comment: I solved it as you suggested applying this method as StackPane.setMargin(textfield, new Insets(1,0,0,20));  // T R B L

Comment: looks like a good idea to read the api doc and learn about the behaviour all available layouts (before choosing the most unfitting ;) unrelated: don't use static scope for the fields

Answer (score 0):

The layout works similar to a `GridPane`. The only problem is that using column/row spans for the chart results in the chart not being used for the calculations of the preferred size of the `GridPane`.

However you could use a `HBox` and a `VBox` to hold the bottom and left textfields respectively and place the `VBox` and the chart in the first row and the `HBox` in the cell below the chart.

The following example uses a `Region` instead of a chart for simplicity, but adjusting the code to use a different node type is trivial:

```
private static TextField createTextField(String prompt) {
    TextField tf = new TextField(prompt);
    return tf;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // Using simple region instead of a chart for simplicity here
    Region chart = new Region();
    chart.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
    chart.setPrefSize(300, 300);

    // create textfield container to the left
    Region placeholder = new Region();
    VBox.setVgrow(placeholder, Priority.ALWAYS);
    VBox left = new VBox(
            createTextField("upperY"),
            placeholder,
            createTextField("lowerY"));

    // create textfield container to the bottom
    placeholder = new Region();
    HBox.setHgrow(placeholder, Priority.ALWAYS);
    HBox bottom = new HBox(
            createTextField("leftX"),
            placeholder,
            createTextField("rightX"));

    GridPane container = new GridPane();
    container.add(left, 0, 0);
    container.add(bottom, 1, 1);
    container.add(chart, 1, 0);

    // make sure the row/column containing the chart is the one that grows
    ColumnConstraints cConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
    cConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    container.getColumnConstraints().addAll(new ColumnConstraints(), cConstraints);

    RowConstraints rConstraints = new RowConstraints();
    rConstraints.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    container.getRowConstraints().addAll(rConstraints, new RowConstraints());

    Scene scene = new Scene(container);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra There's no reason not to. In cases like these I do use the modifier, since this way the compiler/IDE complains in case I accidentally access a non-static member...

Comment: it's the other way round: there should be a compelling reason to use static - we are in OO-land, everything should be an instance ...

Comment: The OO-land needs helper methods too and if they have nothing to do with and instance, I make them static. You may think about this in a different way, but I don't.

Comment: you know what I think about giving bad example - dont dont dont, that's what all the newbies will remember ;) Here is no reason for a helper method, so don't use one ... And even if it were (or seemed to be needed), there's a good probability that there's something wrong in the design